# Can't figure out why sprite doesn't show up on my screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game, and In this game I need a yellow rectangle to show up on the game window, but when I ran the code the yellow rectangle didn't show up. I'm drawing the rectangle in the `Player()` class. Can anyone help me?

main.py

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame
from config import *
from sprites import *

# GAME
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        # INIT PYGAME
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    # NEW GAME
    def new(self):
        self.allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player()
        self.allSprites.add(self.player)
        self.run()

    # RUN GAME
    def run(self):
        self.playing = True

        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)

            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.animate()
            self.collision()

    # DRAW
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)

        pygame.display.update()

    # ANIMATE
    def animate(self):
        pass

    # DETECT COLLISION
    def collision(self):
        pass

    # CHECK FOR EVENTS
    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False

                self.running = False

    # UPDATE GAME
    def update(self):
        self.allSprites.update()

    # GAME OVER
    def gameOver(self):
        pass

    # START SCREEN
    def startScreen(self):
        pass

    # END SCREEN
    def endScreen(self):
        pass

game = Game()
game.startScreen()

while game.running:
    game.new()
    game.gameOver()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

sprites.py

```
import pygame
from config import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.img = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.img.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
        self.vx = 0;
        self.vy = 0;

        def update(self):
            self.vx = 0

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.vx -= 5
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.vx += 5
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.vy -= 5
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.vy += 5

            self.rect.x += self.vx
            self.rect.y += self.vy
```

config.py

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame

# ENTIRE GAME VARIABLES
TITLE = "Sky Jumper"
WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# COLORS
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
```

Comment: use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in varaibles.

Comment: You don't have `self.allSprites.draw()` or `self.player.draw()` so you don't draw it.

Comment: BTW: `self.allSprites.draw()` works only if sprites have `self.rect` and `self.image` but you have `self.img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not drawing your player at all.  The only drawing is happening in your game's draw method, so try adding this:

```
def draw(self):
    self.screen.fill(WHITE)
    self.allSprites.draw(self.screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also, btw, your Player's update() method won't run because it's indented under the **init** method.